# Opencv file format not recognized error

Tags: eclipse, opencv, build, console, file-format

Based on [this](http://share-thevision.blogspot.de/2013/02/opencveclipse-on-windows.html) tutorial I made the install of my opencv. I'm running everything on 64 bits and I'm receiving one compilation error through console output:

```
10:55:25 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project DisplayImage ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-LC:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\mingw\\bin" -o DisplayImage.exe "src\\DisplayImage.o" -lopencv_ml246 -lopencv_imgproc246 -lopencv_core246 -lopencv_highgui246 
C:\opencv\build\x64\mingw\bin/libopencv_ml246.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

10:55:26 Build Finished (took 232ms)
```

"The file is not recognized."

Making one research I found some links like [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43793-Trying-to-use-OpenCV) which complains about the same problem but nobody gave one feedback solution. So, could anybody help me understand why my build is stuck on this part? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sry, I couldnt...If if did I would post here